# use Dojo to programmatically set checkboxes checked

Tags: checkbox, dojo

The codes below returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null. 
what is the correct way to programmatic set checkbox as checked?

```
        array.forEach(this._getAllCheckBoxIDs(), function(item){
            dom.byId(item).checked = true;
        }, this);
```

Comment: This is correct but `dom.byId(item)` returns `null`, so I bet `this._getAllCheckBoxIDs()` does not return what you expect... With a jsfiddle we could provide a better help

Comment: please can you share the content of _getAllCheckBoxIDs() function !

Comment: Appreciate your replies. it turned out that the checkboxes haven't been created when _getAllCheckBoxIDs() was called.

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows a programmatic example on how to set property `checked` for a widget `checkbox`.

The script gets references of your checkboxes using `dijit/registry` opposite to  querying the DOM.

Instead of setting a property directly for your widget like this:

```
dom.byId(item).checked = true;
```

I would suggest using a setter like:

```
widgetReference.set('checked', true);
```

This will allow the widget life-cycle to work properly.

Live example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/femtf4uh/

```
require(["dijit/form/CheckBox", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"], function(CheckBox, registry, Button) {
  new CheckBox({
    id: "checkBox0",
    name: "checkBox0",
    value: "option0",
    checked: false,
    onChange: function(event) {

    }
  }, "checkBox0").startup();
  new CheckBox({
    id: "checkBox1",
    name: "checkBox1",
    value: "option1",
    checked: false,
    onChange: function(event) {

    }
  }, "checkBox1").startup();

  var markCheckAll = function() {
    registry.toArray().forEach(function(widget) {
      if (widget.type === 'checkbox'){
        widget.set('checked', true);
      }
    });
  };
  markCheckAll();

});
```

---

```
<input id="checkBox0" />
<label for="checkBox">Option 0</label>
<br>
<input id="checkBox1" />
<label for="checkBox">Option 1</label>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you you have the collections of dojo checkboxes then I would suggest you to use `registry.byId` instead of `dojo.byId` because you need checkbox dojo widget along with it's domNode to update its attribute.

**dojo class name:-**

```
dijit/registry
```

**Ex:-**

```
// require registry class first
array.forEach(this._getAllCheckBoxIDs(), function(item){
     registry.byId(item).set("checked", true);
}, this);
```

for more details [please click here...](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/registry.html)

Hoping this will help you :)

Comment: make sure "this._getAllCheckBoxIDs()" contains only id of dojo checkboxes.. 
Feel free to shoot your queries if above solutions doesn't work...

Comment: In order to use the proper lifecycle of a dijit widget I would suggest to use instead widget.set('checked', true);

Comment: yup.. Gibbok.. (y)